# How to configure docker to use existing local network

Tags: docker, networking, ubuntu-18.04

I'm trying to make a steam cache and the headache docker wants to use it's own network. I want to force it to use the network my router made so I can connect it properly. I am using [Luke's guide from LinusTechTips](https://linustechtips.com/main/topic/962655-steam-caching-tutorial/). In order to configure the DNS properly, docker has to use the router's network.

Comment: Does the ordinary `docker run -p` option, which makes the container accessible on the host's IP address, meet your needs?

Comment: @DavidMaze Not exactly, I did find out a lot of that guide is outdated. Here's the command for the DNS `docker run --restart unless-stopped --name lancache-dns --detach -p 192.168.0.30:53:53 -e USE_GENERIC_CACHE=true -e UPSTREAM_DNS=8.8.8.8 -e LANCACHE_IP=192.168.0.30 lancachenet/lancache-dns:latest` at this point I thought I had everything going, but a quick test on a second machine revealed this DNS is not working. I believe it's because Docker does not use my host's network. I got this directly from the source, [lancache.net](http://lancache.net/).

Answer (score 1):

1. You can either use host network mode
2. You can create a separate network for docker and make that network interact to host network in the same way as you do for any other network.